# Analysis of the fundamental solution to the heat equation

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations

It is well known that there is a heat kernel (or fundamental solution) of the Cauchy problem for the heat equation on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. I have a simple question. How do I show that the fundamental solution $f(t,x)$ satisfies 
$\lim_{|x|\rightarrow \infty}f(t,x) = 0$ for any fixed t $\gt$ 0

Comment: Something is wrong with your question: you cannot *fix* $x$ if it is a dummy variable. Do you mean "for any fixed $t > 0$"? Or perhaps the limit is for $t\to 0$?

Comment: It should indeed be 'for any fixed t>0'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to show that for any small $\epsilon>0$ that you can find a $t$, or an $x$ depending on what you are asking, and show that the kernel is smaller than $\epsilon$ for any time or point larger than $t$, or $x$ when the other variable is fixed.  The idea is that the error in approximating the kernel with $0$ can be made as small as you like by looking at further points or larger times.